# How can I get the file and line number where a Perl subroutine reference was created?

Tags: perl

Given a subroutine reference, is there a way to find out the file and line number where the subroutine was declared? warn and friends seems to get this right, but I need this externally. Here's my test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;
use B;

# line 99 'bin/some_code.pl'
{
    no strict 'refs';
    print B::svref_2object(\*{'Foo::some_sub'})->LINE;
    print B::svref_2object(\&Foo::some_sub)->GV->LINE;
}
Foo::some_sub();

package Foo;
# line 23 'bin/some_file.pl'
sub some_sub {
    warn "Got to here";
}
```

That outputs:

```
102
102
Got to here at 'bin/some_file.pl' line 24.
```

The line information is not what I'm expecting, so I assume I'm doing something wrong (B::GV has a corresponding FILE method, but until I get LINE working, it's not much use to me).

Is there some other way to get this information and am I doing something wrong in the above code?

*Update*:  As it turns out, the 'FILE' and 'LINE' methods seem to work OK if I'm not using line directives.  Looks like it may be a bug in the B::GV module.

Comment: Perhaps a more detailed explanation of what you're expecting and why would help. It's easy for the casual reader to gloss over the "special" comments in the example without understanding their effect on the line counter.

Answer (score 4):

You could try looking at [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html). This is what the debugger uses to build stack traces, so maybe it is what you want.

I don't think `__LINE__`, `__FILE__` and `__PACKAGE__` help you here as they only provide the location of the *current* point of execution, meaning that given a code reference or sub as in your code you will get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing some of this, but also see the [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org) thread ["Track the filename/line number of an anonymous coderef"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=413725).